# In ssms can I convert 4 column names into one string value only incl. when column int value is 1, then sum ttl of int values in a new column

Tags: sql, ssms

Using ssms v18.

I am looking at hold types for a specific sales order.

The sales order number is a primary id column.

I have 4 additional columns for the hold types. Each column has a Binary value.

I want to concatenate any/all of the column names into one field, when those columns have a value of 1. If none of the columns have a value of 1, then I'd like to enter a string of 'None'.

Then I'd like to create a new column which sums the binary values by order id.

Here is the code I have so far.
I've tried using UNPIVOT, SUM OVER(PARTITION BY) and STRING_AGG but I'm getting some duplicates.

Data set

| order_id | hold_type1 | hold_type2 | hold_type3 | hold_type4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 5 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 6 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| 7 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 9 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 10 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

Wanted Results

| order_id | hold_types | hold_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | None | 0 |
| 2 | hold_type2, hold_type4 | 2 |
| 3 | hold_type1, hold_type2, hold_type3, hold_type4 | 4 |
| 4 | hold_type1 | 1 |
| 5 | hold_type2, hold_type3 | 2 |
| 6 | hold_type3, hold_type4 | 2 |
| 7 | hold_type1, hold_type2, hold_type3 | 3 |
| 8 | hold_type3, hold_type4 | 2 |
| 9 | hold_type1, hold_type3, hold_type4 | 3 |
| 10 | hold_type2 | 1 |

Here is my SQL and one sample of the duplicates I am getting.

Duplicate sample

| order_id | hold_types | hold_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | None | 2 |
| 2 | hold_type2 | 2 |
| 2 | None | 2 |
| 2 | hold_type4 | 2 |

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(
order_id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ,
hold_type1 INT NOT NULL,
hold_type2 INT NOT NULL,
hold_type3 INT NOT NULL,
hold_type4 INT NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO orders
VALUES (0,0,0,0),
(0,1,0,1),
(1,1,1,1),
(1,0,0,0),
(0,1,1,0),
(1,0,0,1),
(1,1,1,0),
(0,0,1,1),
(1,0,1,1),
(0,1,0,0);


WITH data1 AS (SELECT order_id
, hold_types
, hold_total
FROM (SELECT order_id
, hold_type1
, hold_type2
, hold_type3
, hold_type4
FROM orders) AS SourceTable  
UNPIVOT  
(hold_total 
FOR hold_types IN (hold_type1
, hold_type2
, hold_type3
, hold_type4)  
) AS UNPVT
)

SELECT order_id
, CASE WHEN hold_total = 0 THEN 'None'
       WHEN hold_total > 0 THEN STRING_AGG(hold_types,',')
       ELSE NULL END AS hold_types
, SUM(hold_total) OVER(PARTITION BY order_id) AS hold_total
FROM data1
GROUP BY order_id, hold_total, hold_types
```

I also replaced STRING_AGG with CONCAT and the results were the same.

```
CASE WHEN hold_total = 0 THEN 'None'
       WHEN hold_total > 0 THEN CONCAT(hold_types,',')
       ELSE NULL END AS hold_types
```

Thank you!

Comment: ssms is a gui to mamage the database, so your database is sql server or azure

Comment: _"Each column has a Binary value (or maybe int, IDK, 0s and 1s)"_ - those aren't `binary`, they look like `bit` columns. Be aware that `binary`/`varbinary` and `bit` (though you actually have `int`) are very different data-types.

Comment: Yes I think you're correct, that they are bit. I'm still trying to understand these data types. I created it with int just to give a sample.

Comment: @Dai - do you have any insight on how this will impact my specific question?

Comment: It doesn't, I was just providing general feedback and corrections.

Comment: you could try somethng like " ,CONCAT(
   iif(hold_type1=1,'hold_type1',null)+', '
   ,iif(hold_type2=1,'hold_type2',null)+', '
   ,iif(hold_type3=1,'hold_type3',null)+', '
   ,iif(hold_type4=1,'hold_type4',null)
   ,iif(hold_type1+hold_type2+hold_type3+hold_type4 = 0 ,'NONE','')
   )"

Comment: @Kostya why are you using both `+` _and_ `CONCAT` in the same expression? (Also, be-aware that when running SQL Server with ISO/ANSI standards-compliance enabled (which we should all be doing) then `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL` will be `ON` which will break your expression due to `NULL` propagation.

Comment: @Dai CONCAT converts NULL to blank. " null + ', ' " result is null, concat(null, ', ') result is ', '

Answer (score 1):

We `unpivot` and replace the flags with type for 1 and null for 0. Then we can can just `group by order_id` and use `string_agg()`.

```
select   order_id
        ,case when count(flg) = 0 then 'NONE' else string_agg(flg,', ') end as hold_types
        ,count(flg)                                                         as hold_total

from
(
select   order_id
        ,case when flg = 1 then type end as flg
from     t
unpivot  (flg for type in(hold_type1, hold_type2, hold_type3, hold_type4)) up
) t
group by order_id
```

| order_id | hold_types | hold_total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NONE | 0 |
| 2 | hold_type2, hold_type4 | 2 |
| 3 | hold_type1, hold_type2, hold_type3, hold_type4 | 4 |
| 4 | hold_type1 | 1 |
| 5 | hold_type2, hold_type3 | 2 |
| 6 | hold_type1, hold_type4 | 2 |
| 7 | hold_type1, hold_type2, hold_type3 | 3 |
| 8 | hold_type3, hold_type4 | 2 |
| 9 | hold_type1, hold_type3, hold_type4 | 3 |
| 10 | hold_type2 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/D2rSpwHl)

Comment: You're welcome. Please chose the answer and vote up.